# How to specify dependency location in rpm?

Tags: linux, mono, redhat, glibc, rpm

While installing Mono using RPM, GLIBC_2.16 is listed as a dependency. Since I'm having an older version of glibc, and didn't want to corrupt my kernel, i installed the newer glibc from sources in my home folder.

I now want the RPM to refer to this newer glibc lib directory in my home folder while installing mono. What is the RPM option for mentioning dependency locations for a package?

I am currently using the following RPM command:

```
sudo rpm -ivh mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64.rpm
```

I get the following error messages:

```
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit) is needed by mono-core-3.2.3-0.x86_64
```

My newer glibc path is:

```
~/Desktop/glibc/glibc1/lib
```

What option should i include in rpm to reference this path while installing mono?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to install the package without --nodeps unless you install the proper version of glibc in your system.

If your goal is to run mono command completely, it may work fine by the following steps.

1. Installing the package by adding the --nodeps option to rpm command to ignore any dependencies.
2. Running mono-related commands with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to /your/alternative/path/to/glibc.

However, I think that the best solution is to build the mono's source on your machine.